# gitlab-ci: how to interrupt whole stage if one job is failed

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have .gitlab-ci.yml like

```
job1:
  script: heavy_task
  stage: stage

job2:
  script: heavy_task2
  stage: stage
```

I want to run this jobs in parallel as they take a lot of time, When job1 is failed job2 is still running. Is it possible to interrupt it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid its not. Gitlab CI is, as you state, designed to run jobs in parallel.

Comment: It's actually possible to do this using the GitLab API to [Cancel pipeline jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#cancel-a-pipelines-jobs), but it's not a "native" feature.