# gitlab parallel jobs: checking status of one job from other

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've a stage stage `Test` with two parallel running jobs `Job1` and `Job2`. Job1 will process something and Job2 will be monitoring processed data relevant thing in parallel. I want to stop Job2 as soon as Job1 completes.
I thought of doing it through some shared variable/file. So that Job1 will update in it as "completed". Job2 will continuously monitor that shared variable/file along with it's supposed task.
Job2 will exit as soon as it sees Job1 completed status in that shared data/variable.

Challenges, I'm facing

1. I can not use `needs` since I want to run both jobs in parallel not one after another
2. I tried using artifacts, dotenv and global variable. But these are updated and passed to next stage/job only when Job1 has completely finished running

Is there any way to stop `Job2` once `Job1` as completed ?

Closest question I found:
[gitlab-ci: how to interrupt whole stage if one job is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889710/gitlab-ci-how-to-interrupt-whole-stage-if-one-job-is-failed)

EDIT:
Tried with project Variables as suggested in the comments. Though the curl command in job2 is giving blank value

```
Stages:
  - Test

Job1:
  stage: Test
  script:
    - echo "Inside Job1"
    - 'curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/variables" --form "key=myvar" --form "value=someValue"'
  tags:
    - $RUNNER

Job2:
  stage: Test
  script:
    - echo "Inside Job2"
    - sleep 20s
    - 'curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/variables/myvar"'
  tags:
    - $RUNNER
```

Comment: A job can be cancelled programetrically using gitlab api, but then the pipeline status overall will change to "cancelled". There is no other way to acheive your requirement in Gitlab. But I personally wont recommend this as the pipeline status would change to "cancelled".  To cleanly exit the job2 then you need to maintain the status outside. One option is to programatically create a project variable using gitlab api in job 1 and then get the variable value using api in job 2. But all these makes this "hacky" workarounds. So give this a thought, decide if you are still are interested in this.

Comment: I'll be exiting Job2 from the code only. But the problem is how do I know if Job1 has completed. You mentioned Project Variables. So I suppose these can be dynamically updated by any Job and hold the value permanently unlike Artifacts/dotenv which can only be passed

Comment: Are you ok with polling for status of job1 in job2 using Gitlab api? The job api approach is better than using variables and yes, the project variables can be updated dynamically and fetched using Gitlab APIs. As both solutions are API based fetching job status is better than updating variables. Let me know, I can provide you the API details

Comment: @Raghu I believe you are referring me to [CI/CD Project variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html). I've updated the answer with an edit. Please advise what may be wrong here as I'm getting blank value in the runner output

Comment: Yes, project variables. It should work, if the first POST call is executed first. To test add more delay in job2 before you query for the variable. docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html Also a better option would be to use Pipeline API to get the jobs status in the pipeline. With this you get the status of the jobs in the pipeline and dont have to use variables to communicate. Use GET /api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/pipelines/$CI_PIPELINE_ID/jobs/

Comment: Thanks @Raghu. Your suggestion worked.